# Drupal: move it from Apache server to Microsoft server

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

can I easily move my drupal installation from Apache to Microsoft server, or I do need to run the install.php script and reinstall all modules ?

I'm having troubles to connect it to the database, that's why I'm asking. (I get technical problems without specific error messages)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical differences you will encounter are the ones between Apache and IIS. For example, there is no mod_rewrite in IIS, you have to get ISAPIRewrite to play along. You also need the Windows Server to be running MySQL. You may also have .htaccess pathing issues.

Comment: ok thanks. Anyway, I've just moved it and it worked without any change!